# Spring injection for bean with generic wildcard

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have the following:

```
public abstract class ReportGenerationStrategy<T extends ReportParameter> {

    public abstract void generate(T reportParameter) throws IOException;
}
```

The subclasses:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DeferredRevenueReportGenerationStrategy extends ReportGenerationStrategy<DeferredRevenueReportParameter> {


}

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OffBalanceExposureReportGenerationStrategy  extends ReportGenerationStrategy<OffBalanceExposureReportParameter> {


}
```

I am creating a map with the subclasses:

```
@Bean
    public Map<ReportType, ReportGenerationStrategy<? extends ReportParameter>> generationStrategies(
            @Qualifier("deferredRevenueReportGenerationStrategy") final ReportGenerationStrategy<? extends ReportParameter> deferredRevenue,
            @Qualifier("offBalanceExposureReportGenerationStrategy") final ReportGenerationStrategy<? extends ReportParameter> offBalanceExposure
    )
    {
        return ImmutableMap.of(
                ReportType.DEFERRED_REVENUE, deferredRevenue,
                ReportType.OFF_BALANCE_EXPOSURE, offBalanceExposure
        );
    }
```

And trying to inject the map as following:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ReportApplicationServices {


    private final Map<ReportType, ReportGenerationStrategy<ReportParameter>> generationStrategies; //Empty map injected


}
```

But I receive an empty map on the field...

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not sure why it the map isn't working (type erasure?), but I would create a class that wraps the immutable map and then autowire that class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed to use `@Autowire` annotation on the `private final Map` that you have declared.

Hope this helps and solves the issue.